# Dynamically create textboxes,Checkboxes and Lbael for them?

Tags: c#, asp.net

For each button click i want to create text boxes and their corresponding labels dynamically. Please see below code.

```
protected void btnAddField_click( Object sender, EventArgs e ) 
{
CheckBox chkNewField = new CheckBox();
chkNewField.ID      = "chkNewField"+ FieldCount.ToString();
chkNewField.Checked = true;

Label LblNewLabel   = new Label();
LblNewLabel.ID = "lblNewLabel" + FieldCount.ToString();
LblNewLabel.Text    = "New Lable";

TextBox TxtNewLabel = new TextBox();
TxtNewLabel.ID = "TxtNewLabel" + FieldCount.ToString();

Label LblNewValue   = new Label();
LblNewValue.ID = "lblNewValue" + FieldCount.ToString();
LblNewValue.Text = "New Value";

TextBox TxtNewValue = new TextBox();
TxtNewValue.ID = "TxtNewValue" + FieldCount.ToString();

HtmlTableRow  tRow   = new HtmlTableRow ();

HtmlTableCell tCell1 = new HtmlTableCell("th");
HtmlTableCell tCell2 = new HtmlTableCell("th");
tCell2.Attributes.Add( "class", "medium" );
HtmlTableCell tCell3 = new HtmlTableCell("th");
tCell3.Attributes.Add( "class", "medium" );
HtmlTableCell tCell4 = new HtmlTableCell();
HtmlTableCell tCell5 = new HtmlTableCell("th");
tCell5.Attributes.Add( "class", "medium" );
HtmlTableCell tCell6 = new HtmlTableCell("th");
tCell6.Attributes.Add( "class", "medium" );

tCell1.Controls.Add(chkNewField);
tCell2.Controls.Add(LblNewLabel);
tCell3.Controls.Add(TxtNewLabel);
tCell4.Controls.Add( new LiteralControl( "" ) );
tCell5.Controls.Add( LblNewValue );
tCell6.Controls.Add( TxtNewValue );

tRow.Cells.Add(tCell1);
tRow.Cells.Add(tCell2);
tRow.Cells.Add(tCell3);
tRow.Cells.Add(tCell4);
tRow.Cells.Add(tCell5);
tRow.Cells.Add(tCell6);

tblPropertyCustom.Rows.Add(tRow );
FieldCount++;
```

}

It's showing only one row of labels and fields. On next click the row values will replace by next counted labels and fields. Please help me(I can see only 1 row).